# Python list elements vs converting to tuple for string formatting

Tags: python, performance, optimization, tuples

I came across a problem on codewars and am not sure what the difference is between these two possible solutions, one converting a list into a tuple and one specifying elements of the input list.

Problem: convert a list of names (strings) to a statement similar to what Facebook uses to display likes: "Alex likes this", "Alex and John like this", "Alex, John and 2 others like this", etc.

Using a if-elif-etc statement, this is pretty trivial:

```
    if len(names) == 0:
        output_string = "no one likes this"
    elif len(names) == 1:
        output_string = str(names[0]) + " likes this"
```

But in the longer lists of names, you have a choice:

```
    elif len(names) == 2:
        output_string = "%s and %s like this" % (names[0], names[1])
```

**OR**

```
    elif len(names) == 3:
        output_string = "%s, %s and %s like this" % tuple(names)
```

My hypothesis is that it's more computationally efficient to use `names[0]` etc, because you don't create a new object in memory for the tuple - is that right?

Comment: Why is computational efficiency a concern here? In the real world you're going to send a string like this across the Internet, which is *vastly* slower than anything you could come up with here.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am mostly curious what's a better practice - my first move was to convert to tuples but that was based on "too lazy to type out list indices" and I couldn't figure out if it was an okay way to do it our not. That's a great point though - why bother worrying about it, either is probably okay enough.

Comment: A note: "[I]t's more computationally efficient to use `names[0]` etc, because you don't create a new object in memory for the tuple" is based on a faulty premise. `(names[0], names[1], names[2])` is building a `tuple` just as much as `tuple(names)` does. The former is a `tuple` literal, the latter is a call to the `tuple` constructor, but they both make "a new object in memory for the `tuple`" (or not; `tuple` makes extensive use of free lists, so it often just pulls an available `tuple` off the free list for reuse).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CPython optimization rules are usually based around how much work you push to the C layer (vs. the bytecode interpreter) and how complex the bytecode instructions are; for low levels of absolute work, the fixed overhead of the interpreter tends to swamp the real work, so intuition derived from experience in lower-level languages just doesn't apply.

It's pretty easy to test though, especially with `ipython`'s `%timeit` magic (timings done on Python 3.8.5 on Alpine Linux running under WSLv2):

```
In [2]: %%timeit l = [1, 2, 3]
   ...: tuple(l)
97.6 ns ± 0.303 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [3]: %%timeit l = [1, 2, 3]
   ...: (l[0], l[1], l[2])
104 ns ± 0.561 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [4]: %%timeit l = [1, 2, 3]
   ...: (*l,)
78.1 ns ± 0.628 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [5]: %%timeit l = [1, 2]
   ...: tuple(l)
96 ns ± 0.895 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [6]: %%timeit l = [1, 2]
   ...: (l[0], l[1])
70.1 ns ± 0.571 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [7]: %%timeit l = [1, 2]
   ...: (*l,)
73.4 ns ± 0.736 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

So in fact, the code example you gave made the correct decision for each size (assuming performance is all that counts); at two elements, indexing is faster than the alternatives, at three, converting to `tuple` in bulk saves enough over repeated indexing to win.

Just for fun, I included an equivalent solution to `tuple(l)` up there that using the additional unpacking generalizations to build the `tuple` using dedicated bytecodes, which shows how something as small as replacing a generalized constructor call with dedicated optimized bytecode can make a surprisingly amount of difference in the fixed overhead.

What's extra fun about this example: The faster `(*l,)` solution actually involves two temporaries; `BUILD_TUPLE_UNPACK` (the byte code that implements it) shares a code path with `BUILD_LIST_UNPACK`. Both of them actually build a `list`, and `BUILD_TUPLE_UNPACK` just converts it to `tuple` at the end. So `(*l,)` is hiding yet another copy to a temporary data structure, but because the specialized bytecode is so much more efficient than built-in lookup plus general purpose constructor code paths, it still wins.

Comment: FYI, `BUILD_TUPLE_UNPACK` as a bytecode ends with 3.8; in 3.9, they went with a different approach to the unpacking generalizations. But the behavior of having it build a `list` first, and just convert to `tuple` at the end remains the same (there's a dedicated `LIST_TO_TUPLE` bytecode for that precise purpose). But in 3.9, `(*l,)` doesn't seem to win anymore (at least on a hand-compiled build that may be more efficient that the `apk` package Alpine installed for 3.8.5); both of them run significantly faster (~40 ns), but `tuple(l)` wins by 0.5-1.5 ns. Go figure.

Comment: oh wow, thank you! I didn't even know about the `(*l,)` option, and it hadn't really occurred to me that the answer might be different for 2 vs 3 elements.

Comment: @trish_s: I knew this general pattern already (I play with `%%timeit` magic to procrastinate, and for funsies). Indexing is one of the things in Python where the overhead relative to real work is unusually high (it's one of many reasons to discourage `for i in range(len(someseq)): someseq[i]` over the more Pythonic `for x in someseq: x`), so I knew adding one element could absolutely make the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use the [disassembler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) to see what bytecode Python generates for this:

```
>>> names=['alex', 'ramon', 'carla']
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis('abc')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (abc)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis('"%s, %s and %s like this" % tuple(names)')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('%s, %s and %s like this')
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (tuple)
              4 LOAD_NAME                1 (names)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 BINARY_MODULO
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis('"%s, %s and %s like this" % (names[0], names[1], names[2])')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('%s, %s and %s like this')
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (names)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR
              8 LOAD_NAME                0 (names)
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR
             14 LOAD_NAME                0 (names)
             16 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             18 BINARY_SUBSCR
             20 BUILD_TUPLE              3
             22 BINARY_MODULO
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

The fact that the disassembler shows there are a lot more instructions for the second approach doesn't *necessarily* mean it's slower. After all, a function call is just the opaque `CALL_FUNCTION`. So you have to use judgement and know what that's doing. But it seems you're building a tuple either way…

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look of your code visualization (shows memory units used by your code)**

[image: Visualization of your code]

In your code, the type you stored in output_string is a string. Even though you wrote tuple(names) in memory there will be no memory allocation to a tuple. Consider the above visualization of your code in memory terms.

Comment: I don't know where you get the idea there is no memory allocation. The `tuple` is constructed, used as the right operand to `%` to build the string, then discarded; it's still made. It might not actually allocate memory to do it (I see nothing that says that in what you posted, but you're coincidentally correct about this), because CPython's `tuple` maintains a free list for the small `tuple` sizes that it uses to minimize allocation requests, but it's still taking something unused and making it used, if only for a few nanoseconds.